# how to get processor that thread is currently assigned to?

Tags: linux, process, cpu, ps

I've found such column in `ps -elF`:

```
PSR processor that process is currently assigned to.
```

I need something similar but for threads. `ps huH p 1234` prints threads of process 1234, can I somehow add "PSR" column to this output?

**upd:** ok I've found `ps -LPp 1234` what answers this question. But I prefer live outout. So can i somehow add "PSR" column to `top -H p 1234`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me the best:

1. install htop. `yum install htop`
2. To enable thread views in htop, launch htop, and press  to enter htop setup menu. Choose "Display option" under "Setup" column, and toggle on "Three view" and "Show custom thread names" options.
3. Also add PROCESSOR column in settings;
4. Presss  to exit the setup.

To find process by pid just start typing pid when htop is running.